# How show the normal text read from a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I'm with the following problem: I'm brazilian, and here we use strange characters like 'ç' or 'ã'. So, I'm programming for web and when I read the text file and show its content, it replaces the strange characters for '?'.

EDITED:

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(getImages);
function getImages() {
    $.getJSON("/home/ListImagesProducts", showImages);
}

function showImages(data) {
    $("#directoryImages").append("<ul id = 'productImages'>");
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var directories = data[i];

        $("#directoryImages ul").append("<li><img src='../Content/images/Products/" + directories.ImageName + "' /><div class = 'description'> ççç" + directories.DescriptionName + "</li>");
    }
    //$("#directoryImages").append("</ ul>");
}
```

The 'ççç' before the 'directories.DescriptionName' are shown normainly. I'm reading the text from a notepad file. I already put 'UTF-8'.

How can I show the normal text read from the file?

Comment: How are you reading the text file?  Please include some code.  Is it coming from a server, or using the FileAPI?

Comment: Character encodings. Use UTF-8.

Comment: Sounds like you might have a font problem, rather than an encoding problem.

Comment: The text file is comming from a local directory.

Answer (score 2):

You need the **UTF-8** character encoding for your document

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
<meta charset=utf-8 />    
<title>My page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p>çãšđčćž</p>

</body>
</html>
```

theremore if you use some text editor (like Notepad++) make sure to set encoding:

**Encode in UTF-8 Without BOM**

Additionally you have some errors in your code. You messed up with `'` and `"` and you don't have the closing `</div>`

```
src='../Content/images/Products/" + directories.ImageName + "' /><div class = 'description'> ççç" + directories.DescriptionName + "</li>"
```

should be:

```
src='../Content/images/Products/' + directories.ImageName + ' /><div class="description"> ççç ' + directories.DescriptionName + '</div></li>'
```

Instead of using `.append()` inside a for loop (which is terribly slow) create a string, populate it inside the `for loop` and than append it only once:

```
var ul = "<ul id='productImages'>";

for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var directories = data[i];
    ul += "<li><img src='../Content/images/Products/" + directories.ImageName + "' /><div class = 'description'> ççç" + directories.DescriptionName + "</div></li>";
}

ul += "</ul>";

$("#directoryImages").append( ul );
```

Comment: I do not want to offend. Sorry. I just already tried by this way :)

Comment: @LucasBorsatto :) all fine, any way, fix your errors and try again

Comment: @LucasBorsatto - I found more issues in your code. Edited my answer